# Amazon Dynamo DB max client connections?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, connection-pooling, amazon-dynamodb

When creating an AmazonDynamoDBClient in the Java API we can specify the maximum connection pool size using setMaxConnections on ClientConfiguration. Is there a hard / recommended limit on this? For example although the default limit is 50 connections a linux client should be able to sustain 5,000 open connections, will Amazon allow this?

If there is a maximum limit does it only apply to a single client instance? What about if there are several machines using dynamo through the same account, will they share a connection limit?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know on the Amazon side but beware: too many opened connections are most likely to degrade your own server performances first.

Comment: True, just wondering which will come first, an amazon api limit or degradation or my own.

Answer (score 6):

Since the connections to Amazon DynamoDB is http(s) based, the concept of open connections is limited to your tcp max open connections at once. I highly doubt there's a limit on Amazons end at all as it is load balanced close to infinity.

Naturally, the exception is your read and write capacity limits. Note that they want you to contact them if you will exceed a certain amount of capacity units which depend on your region.

You've probably already read them, but the limitations of DynamoDB is found here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html